# Magento sampledata sales banners

Tags: magento2, blocks, widgets, sample-data, banner-slider

I have some questions regarding the sales banners on sample data Magento sites. For example the below banner

[image: Banner in question on the sample data site]

In the blocks editor, the html code for this block looks like this:

```
<a class="block-promo sale-main" href="{{store url=&quot;&quot;}}">
<img src="{{media url=&quot;wysiwyg/sale/sale-main.jpg&quot;}}"alt="">
<span class="content">
<span class="info">Women’s Deals</span>
<strong class="title">Pristine prices on pants, tanks and bras</strong>
<span class="more button">Shop Women’s Deals</span>
</span>
</a>
```

Where do i find and use these kinds of banners? Are they included by default in every Magento installation or are they something implemented at the theme level with the sample data?

Comment: You can find content in static blocks, the content is rendering using widgets and it bundle with sample data.

Comment: I think above is the `home-page-block` block and widget title is `Home Page`.